# SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘empty table’)

Tags: sql, sql-server

i use

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)
```

to get calculate the next id but for the empty table it returns 1 not 0

how can i get 0 for the empty tables

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does your identity start from 0 or 1? By default it starts from 1

take a look

```
CREATE TABLE TestIdent(id INT IDENTITY)
GO
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TestIdent')  -- 1



CREATE TABLE TestIdent2(id INT IDENTITY(0,1))
GO
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TestIdent2')  -- 0
```

Comment: I understand, the OP's point is that the value returned by `IDENT_CURRENT` on an empty table can't be told from the value returned on the same table after the first (successful) insert into it.

Comment: Actually DBCC CHECKIDENT (Tablename, NORESEED) gives you the correct result if table is empty. There is a difference in what these 2 functions do with empty tables I think.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT case
         when count(*) = 0 then 0
         else ident_current('Mytable')
       end
 from Mytable
```

Comment: That won't work if you delete all the rows from the table, it doesn't reseed the table, truncate will

Comment: It depends on what they want. If they always need a 0 for an empty table regardless of possible prior contents (which is how I read the question), this would work. If they need the increment value to be assigned by the next insert, they'd need to work with DBCC Checkident. Unless they've reseeded to less than the current max value... at which the scope of the problem becomes far too complex without knowing the details of the problem being addressed.